# PHP & Wordpress: How do I display a list of all users who have completed a custom user meta field, omitting those where the field is left empty?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On a Wordpress site I'm developing, I have created a fcustom user meta field (matrix-diagnosis) where people can add additional information.

I'm trying to display a list of all users who have completed this field (and their response), but would like to omit those who have not completed the field.

After a LOT of Googling, the closest I've gotten is this bit of code...

```
<ul class="unstyled">

<?php
  //these are the arguments for the get_users function below
  $args  = array(
     'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
     'meta_query' => array('key' => 'matrix-diagnosis')
  );

  //get_users calls WP_User_Query and returns an array of matching users
  $users = get_users($args);

  //leaving an array of $users sorted by the value of meta 'points'
  foreach ($users as $user) : ?>

     <li>
        <h3><?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $user->id ); ?> <?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $user->id ); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'matrix-diagnosis', $user->id ); ?></p>
     </li>

<?php endforeach; /* end for each function */ ?>

</ul>
```

This actually will query the database and display a list of all users and their responses, but if someone has not completed the field, displays just their name. How do I scrub the list of people for whom that field has no value?

I have a hunch the secret lies not in using an array, but in using the $wpdp tag, which I have had no luck with to date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using WP_User_Query and meta_compare instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change `the_author_meta( 'matrix-diagnosis', $user->id );` to `$matrix_check = get_the_author_meta( 'matrix-diagnosis', $user->id, true );` and on your foreach statment check if empty like:

```
foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
<?php $matrix_check = get_the_author_meta( 'matrix-diagnosis', $user->id, true );
if ($matrix_check != "") {?>
     <li>
        <h3><?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $user->id ); ?> <?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $user->id ); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'matrix-diagnosis', $user->id ); ?></p>
     </li>
```

**Note: Not tested, some tags not closed**

Comment: Well that was easy! Thank you SO much! I tried so many combinations of if statements, and none of them were working. Looks like adding "get" to the_author_meta was the trick.

Comment: For anyone else that finds this, I added a $ to matrix_check in the if statement.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi check the docs, the_autor_meta echoes the value, and get_the_author_meta, passes the value to a string or variable. That applies to other wordpress functions. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Comment: Thanks again. I'm VERY new to PHP, and programming in general (spent most of my career doing CSS/HTML up to this point), so I'm still learning. Cheers!